# Conditional, term-wise addition of sublist slices

Tags: python, list, sum

I have a list of lists :

```
ls = [['01',2,3,4], ['02',5,2,4], ['03',2,6,4], ['01',1,3,4]]
```

I want to add the terms of the sublist after the string with their corresponding ones from all other sublists beginning with the same string.

So the result should look like this:

```
result = [['01',3,6,8], ['02',5,2,4], ['03',2,6,4]]
# the first and last original sublists were "combined"
```

I tried this code:

```
ls=[['01',2,3,4],['02',5,2,4],['03',2,6,4],['01',1,3,4]]
totals = {}
for key, value1,value2,value3 in ls:
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value1
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value2
    totals[key] = totals.get(key, 0) + value3

print(totals)
```

but it is not my goal:

```
{'01': 17, '02': 11, '03': 12}
```

Comment: Based on what criteria do you determine the output? Post that as well.

Comment: result = [['01',3,6,8]['02',5,2,4],['03',2,6,4]]

Comment: It's good that you have posted the desired output but how are you arriving at such a result?

Comment: @J...S I guess it's a group by sum in array form.

Comment: @absolutelydevastated Yes, That's I need

Comment: You are adding values, but you want to add lists of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small amendment of your code, I have initialised the values `[0, 0, 0]` when there is a new 'key'.

```
ls = [['01', 2, 3, 4],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4],['01', 1, 3, 4]]
totals = {}
for key, value1, value2, value3 in ls:
    if key not in totals.keys():
        totals[key] = [0, 0, 0]
    totals[key][0] += value1
    totals[key][1] += value2
    totals[key][2] += value3

totals = [[k] + v for k, v in totals.items()]
print(totals)

# Output:
# [['01', 3, 6, 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
```

The first problem of your code is that `totals.get(key, 0)` will give you `0` not our desired initial value `[0, 0, 0]` when you have a new key.

Second, you are summing all the values of the list in your for loop instead of summing the list element-wise. Therefore, you are getting `{'01': 17, '02': 11, '03': 12}`

---

Version 2 (more generic, and handle non-numbers)

```
ls = [['01', 2, 'a', 4],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4],['01', 1, 'ad', 4]]
totals = {}
for x in ls:
    if x[0] not in totals.keys():
        totals[x[0]] = x[1:]
    else:
        for i in range(len(totals[x[0]])):
            if isinstance(x[1 + i], (int, float)):
                totals[x[0]][i] += x[1 + i]

totals = [[k] + v for k, v in totals.items()]
print(totals)

# Output:
# [['01', 3, 'a', 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
```

Comment: How I amend your code if  mylist (ls) have upto n value and some of them are not integers to sum. Suppose that if they are not intergers then we wont sum value and keep the first one

Comment: @TuanNguyen I have edited my answer, see if it suits your purpose.

Comment: ls = [['01', 2, 'a', 4],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4],['01', 1, 'ad', 4]] - I want result: ls = [['01', 3, 'a', 8],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4]]

Answer (score 0):

You can use setdefault along with some indexing to get the desired results.

```
ls=[['01',2,3,4],['02',5,2,4],['03',2,6,4],['01',1,3,4]]
totals = {}
for element in ls:
    key ,array = element[0],element[1:]
    for index in range(len(array)):
        totals.setdefault(key,[0]*len(array))[index] += array[index]    
result = []
for key,value in totals.items():
    result.append([key] + value)
print(result)

# you can sort the result to get exactly as you wanted
# you dont need this step if the dictionary is already sorted like in python3
result.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

print(result)
```

Edit to handle the case where characters come and the first character gets selected

```
ls=[['01',2,'a',4],['02',5,2,4],['03',2,3,4],['01',1,'asd',4]]
totals = {}
for element in ls:
    key ,array = element[0],element[1:]
    for index in range(len(array)):
        if key not in totals:
            totals.setdefault(key,array)    
        elif (type(totals[key][index]) == "int") and type(array[index] == "int"):    
            totals[key][index] += array[index]    
result = []
for key,value in totals.items():
    result.append([key] + value)
print(result)

# you can sort the result to get exactly as you wanted
# you dont need this step if the dictionary is already sorted like in python3
result.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])

print(result)
```

OUTPUT

In python 2

```
[['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4], ['01', 3, 6, 8]]
[['01', 3, 6, 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
```

In python 3

```
[['01', 3, 6, 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
[['01', 3, 6, 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
```

Comment: Can you explain to me the code: totals.setdefault(key,[0]*len(array))[index] += array[index] do ?

Comment: @TuanNguyen setdefault will create key, default value if the key doesnt exist and updates the value if the key already exists in the dictionary. the key is key and the default value is [0] * len(array) which is an list of zeros of the length of list `array` . ` totals.setdefault(key,[0]*len(array))` is like selecting 'totals[key]' with setting a default value to it if key doesnt exist. Then we update the array `totals[key]` with the index of corresponding element in the list `array`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get your question, you are essentially trying to do a group by then an array sum. Personally, I would do this:

```
sum_dictionary = {}

for ls in your_list:
    key = ls[0]
    vals = ls[1:]
    if key not in sum_dictionary:
        sum_dictionary[key] = [vals]
    else:
        sum_dictionary[key].append(vals)

for k, v in sum_dictionary.items():
    sum_dictionary[k] = list(map(sum, zip(*v)))
```

Comment: I try your code and get error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Code\Practice\Getdata.py", line 56, in <module>
    sum_dictionary[k] = list(map(sum, zip(*v)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: python -u "D:\Code\Practice\Getdata.py"]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you didn't slice the input and kept the key still. The rest of the list should be integers. I tried this with sample data and it worked.

Comment: Sorry, but i've tried and get {'01': [2, 3, 4, [2, 9, 4]], '02': [5, 2, 4], '03': [2, 6, 4]} so sum_dictionary[k] = list(map(sum, zip(*v))) get error (lack of "]")

Comment: Sorry there was a typo, `val` should be in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Something a bit more elegant maybe that uses [`groupby` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


ls = [['01', 2, 3, 4], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4], ['01', 1, 3, 4]]

res = []
for k, group in groupby(sorted(ls), itemgetter(0)):
  group = [sub[1:] for sub in group]
  res.append([k] + [sum(x) for x in zip(*group)])

print(res)  # -> [['01', 3, 6, 8], ['02', 5, 2, 4], ['03', 2, 6, 4]]
```

---

Note that the above solution will sort the original list `ls`!

Comment: Suppose that my ls = [['01', 2, 'a', 4],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4],['01', 1, 'ad', 4]] How I can get the output: ls = [['01', 3, 'a', 8],['02', 5, 2, 4],['03', 2, 6, 4]]

Comment: is that in the last sublist an `'ad'` or an `'a'`?

Comment: 'ad'. I suppose that coz i want to keep the first value